# onStart method is called AFTER onComplete method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton, onstart

I have a button let's call it "Button1":

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-document"
  value="Button1"
  onstart="#{bean.populateDependancies(item)}"
  update="myDialog"
  oncomplete="dialogWidget.show();">
</p:commandButton>
```

This `Button1` is supposed to open a `dialog`, but **BEFORE** opening it I want it to populate the target of the primefaces picklist **in** the dialog with some values (this job is done by the method `populateDependancies(item)`).

But actually the method `populateDependancies(item)` is called when I **close** the dialog and **hit** the validateEdition button of `cellEditor` of primefaces (or even the cancel button) (NB: `Button1` is placed in a column of an editable datatable).

I hope I clearly explained the problem... Please let me know if something remains unclear

---

Here is my page structure maybe it could help:
[image]

and here is my method:

```
public void populateDependancies(Release release) {
    if (release != null) {
        if (rfcsDualListModel.getTarget() != null || !rfcsDualListModel.getTarget().isEmpty()) {
            rfcsDualListModel.setTarget(null);
        }
        List<Rfc> rfcDejaAssocies = release.getRfcs();
        rfcsDualListModel.setTarget(rfcDejaAssocies);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try "actionListener" instead of "onstart"

Comment: Already tried and the button don't call the method at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onstart` executes javascript code, just like `oncomplete`. `#{bean.populateDependancies(item)}` must be the value of `action` or `actionListener` attributes.

edit: in addition, `process="@this"` attribute and value must be used, in order not to submit the whole form.

Comment: I already tried action and actionListener instead of onStart, and no one worked. They don't call the method. That's very strange because I checked the method signature and it's alright

Comment: could you paste the code of whole form `Button1` is nested in?

Comment: I edited my question and added the structure of my xhtml page... maybe it would offer some clarification

Comment: yes, using `process="@this"` was my second alternative. that attribute decides which fields will be submitted with that request. if you do not set it to `@this`, all the form that the button is nested in will be submitted to server side. in that case, it messes up with a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using `actionListener` AND `process="@this"` attribute of the commandButton.. But I honestly don't know why it worked only by adding `process="@this"`.. If someone knows the reason.. please let me know. Thanks to all.

Comment: Next time post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get better help sooner. See also our [jsf info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: Thank you @perissf but I thought that the code I posted was enough to illustrate the problem. Isn't it?

Comment: The default is @form so that sounds very strange. Try deleting it again

Comment: An idea could be that when using @form one of the other input fields causes an exception, causing the method to not be run